# Apache Flink flatMap with millions of outputs

Tags: apache-flink

Whenever i receive a message, i want to do a read from a database, possibly returning millions of rows, which i then want to pass on down the stream. Is this considered good practice in Flink?

```java
public static class StatsReader implements FlatMapFunction<Msg, Json> {

    Transactor txor = 
        ...;

    @Override
    public void flatMap(Msg msg, Collector<Json> out) {

        //Possibly lazy and async stream
        java.util.Stream<Json> results = 
            txor.exec(Stats.read(msg)); 

        results.foreach(stat->out.collect(stat));

    }
}
```

Edit:

Background: I would like to dynamically run a report. The db basically acts as a huge window. The report is based on that window + live data. The report is highly customizable, threfore its hard to preprocess results or define pipelines a priori.

I use vanilla java today, and the pipeline is roughly like this:
ReportDefinition -> ( elasticsearch query + realtime stream ) -> ( ReportProcessingPipeline ) -> ( Websocket push )

Comment: FIrst impression: that sounds like a bad idea. Can you give us more context -- what's the bigger picture?

Comment: @alpinegizmo, i added som background in the question.

Answer (score 3):

In principle this should be possible. However, I'd recommend to use an [`AsyncFunction`](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/stream/operators/asyncio.html) instead of a `FlatMapFunction`.

Please note that, such a setup might require tuning the checkpointing parameters, such as the checkpoint interval.

Comment: But the async function only accepts a single value according to the docs. Or is there another Async way?

Comment: You can emit multiple values but they have to be passed as a `Collection` (see [`ResultFuture.complete()`](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-streaming-java/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/functions/async/ResultFuture.java#L42)). Hence, they must fit into memory.

Comment: That is my main concern, the data will probably not fit into memory